# JSoup- Getting text between tags as is

Tags: java, jsoup, apache-tika

**Scenario:** I used `Apache Tika` to get `XHTML` from a `DOCX` file. I need to parse this `XHTML` to get text between particular tags (e.g. div or p tag). For this I use `Jsoup` to get text between tags.

**Problem:** Originally the `XHTML` has this text:

```
some text [tab-space][tab-space] other text.
```

But with `Jsoup` i am getting this:

```
some text other text.
```

So the tag spaces are missing but i need to get the text as is i.e. including `tag-spaces`. Is it possible to do this using `Jsoup` or is there any other `Java` library to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the getWholeText method for TextNodes: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#getWholeText--

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(".\\source.xhtml"), "UTF-8");

for (Element result : doc.select("div")) {
    final String text = ((TextNode) result.childNode(0)).getWholeText();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```